# How to show ~year(s) ~month(s) ~day(s) has been passed using NSdate- swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I'm playing with swift. I want to show how many years/months/days has been passed since the specific date(NSdate).

If the specific date is 08/01/2016 and current date is 08/11/2016, it will show only "10day(s) has been passed". If the specific date is 08/11/2015, it will show "1year(s) 0 month(s) 0day(s)has been passed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this. Use your dates in `date1` and `date2`

```
let date1 = NSDate()
let date2 = NSDate()

let form = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
form.maximumUnitCount = 2
form.unitsStyle = .Full
form.allowedUnits = [.Year, .Month, .Day]
let s = form.stringFromDate(date1, toDate: date2)
```